# How to get association class attribute in rdlc dataset

Tags: rdlc

i have a class name **student** and associated **course** class. my class look like

```
public int StudentId { get; set; }
public String FirstName { get; set; }
public String LastName { get; set; }
public String FatherName { get; set; }
public String MotherName { get; set; }
public String Country { get; set; }
private List<Course> _courseList = new List<Course>();
public List<Course> CourseList
    {
        get { return _courseList; }
        set { _courseList = value; }
    }
```

if i use the student class as rdlc report dataset. it shows all student class attribute & List of Course class. is it possible to get the course class attribute from the List for rdlc report design...?